# Commercial PHP Job Board Script

Tags: php

I found some but still want to know more about them. Any of you using a very good (commercial will do) PHP Job Board Script.

Comment: You might want to be more specific about what you are looking for. The way the question is phrased right now makes it a Yes/No question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks good: http://www.jobberbase.com/

Answer (score 0):

I find this [job board script](http://www.truworthit.com/products/job-board-software.php) to be really cool.

Oh it is commercial though !!